# expected value, random variable, piecewise function

Tags: probability, integration, statistics, normal-distribution

I hope that you can help me with the following problem:

Let $X \sim \mathcal N\left(\mu, \sigma^2\right)$ be a random variable. Define a new random variable $Y$ as:

$$
 Y = g(X) =
  \begin{cases}
   a(z+X) & \text{if } (z+X) \leq k \\
   ak + b(z+X-k)        & \text{if } (z+X) > k,
  \end{cases}
$$ 
where $a$, $b$, $k$, and $z$ are scalars. I want to calculate the expected value of $E(Y)$. Unfortunately, I don't know how to proceed. I guess I should apply the transformation theorem:

$$
E(Y) = \int _{-\infty}^{\infty} g(x)dF_x(x)
$$

But I don't know hot to apply it to $g(X)$.Thank you for your help!

Answer (score -1):

For a random variable $X$ with finite first and second moments (i.e. expectation and variance exist) it holds that $\forall c\in\mathbb R$, $\mathbb E[cX]=c\mathbb E[X]$.

In your case it is going to be pretty straight forward assuming that $a$,$b$,$k$ and $z$ are scalars and that the expectation of a normal distribution is the mean $\mu$:

$$
\mathbb E[a(z+X)] = \mathbb E[az + aX] =  \mathbb E[az] + \mathbb E[aX] = az + a\mathbb E[X] = az + aμ$$ for $k\leqslant z+X$.

Now just follow the same line of thought for the other equation.

Comment: You need to compute $E[a(z+X)1_{\{z+X\leq k\}}]$, not $E[a(z+X)]$.